# grizzly logs to stderr, annoying in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, logging, junit, jersey, grizzly

When i run my junit jersey service tests using the grizzly framework in eclipse, the log is directed to stderr.  As a result the console window grabs focus, and the log appears red.

I can't figure out the proper configuration steps.  From my reading it looks like i need to add the slf4j.jar to my pom.xml and add a logging properties file somewhere?  But i'm unsure which slf4j jars to add (there are many) or where to place the logging properties file.

Or, frankly, if this is the right approach in general.

p.s. also i am aware i can turn off the "show console when standard error changes" feature in eclipse, but i'd rather not paint over the problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like Grizzly used slf4j, but rather the "standard" java.util.logging framework. If that's the case, you can read about configuring it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#1.8

Answer (score 2):

With Eric's help above I created this class:

```
package org.trebor.www;

import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoggerTrap
{
  public LoggerTrap()
  {
    Handler handler = 
      new ConsoleHandler()
    {
      {
        setOutputStream(System.out);
      }
    };

    Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(handler);
  }
}
```

and added this jvm arg

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.class=org.trebor.www.LoggerTrap
```

and all java.logging goes to STDOUT.  In the process I've learned that I don't much like java.logging.

Comment: You're not alone (and log4j isn't any better). slf4j has been my preference for several years now.

Comment: Were you able to get Grizzly log output to show up?  I had the same red output problem and used your solution to fix it but have the problem that after that I see no logging from Grizzly at all.  I've tried with and without mentioning grizzly in my log4j.properties file.  Any hints on how to see Grizzly logging?  Thanks!