# Redirect 3rd party library logging to another slf4j log file

Tags: java, slf4j, jersey-2.0, java.util.logging, grizzly

I am a Java newbie so please excuse any incorrect terminology.

My Java application uses SLF4j which I have configured to use the SimpleLogger implementation and redirect log messages to a file.

The application uses the Jersey framework which depends on Grizzly, which as far as I can tell, uses the standard java.util.logging framework.

When I run the application the output from my log statements appears in the lof file as expected but the output from Grizzly's log statements appears in the console in red.

Ideally, I would like to redirect the Grizzly log output to my file. Is this possible?

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9092276/820657) answer I was able to redirect the Grizzly output to a different file and I can turn it off altogether with:

```
Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33890249/820657) but the only answer provided is not helpful and was not accepted.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you directing your logs to a file? Are you using logback?

Comment: No, via `SimpleLogger`.